# Simple sample query working update but skips the first condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code that updates the value in 2 tables and I used left join. It works but it keeps on skipping the first condition and always enters the second condition. I have no idea on mysql injection so please advice if my code is prone to mysql injection.

```
elseif ($_POST['check'])
{
    if ($row[typeofdog] = 'Labrador') 
    {
            $id = $_POST['data'];   
            $count = count($id);

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
            {

            $sql = "UPDATE animals LEFT JOIN treats ON animals.style = treats.style SET animals.bone = bone - treats.total, treats.status = 'Approved' WHERE treats.id='$id[$i]'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            }

        if($result){header("location:login_success.php");}

    }
    else
    {
        $id = $_POST['data'];   
        $count = count($id);

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
            {

            $sql = "UPDATE animals LEFT JOIN treats ON animals.style = treats.style SET animals.chunks = chunks - treats.total, treats.status = 'Approved' WHERE treats.id='$id[$i]'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            }

        if($result){header("location:login_success.php");}

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error

Comment: You're using = instead of == ( logical error not a syntax one)

Comment: There is a syntax error in there as well.

Comment: Thanks for th reply. I did this `if ($row[typeofdog] == 'Labrador') ` and it still skips the first condition.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem, but `$row[typeofdog]` is incorrect. PHP is smart enough to figure out what you mean, but the correct syntax is `$row['typeofdog']`.

Comment: @relentless Sir can you point out what is the syntax error in the code?

Answer (score 2):

First, `=` is for assignment. `==` is for comparison.

Second, using the index `typeofdog` without quotes is incorrect. [**PHP explains why here.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Try this:

```
if ($row['typeofdog'] == 'Labrador')
```

If this doesn't work, then `$row['typeofdog']` does not equal `'Labrador'`. In that case, try echoing `$row['typeofdog']` just before the conditional so you can see what is being compared.

Also, yes, you are at risk for sql injection. First step to fixing this: **[don't use mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**. Instead use [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**pdo**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and utilize [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Tried one given by you sir but its not working either.

Comment: @Patrick Did you `echo $row['typeofdog'];` before the `if`. Are you sure it equals 'Labrador'?